# How to get Alembic to recognise SQLModel database model?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic, pydantic, sqlmodel

Using [SQLModel](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel) how to get alembic to recognise the below model?

```
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel

class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None
```

One approach I've been looking at is to import the SQLalchemy model for Alembic but looking through the source code I can't find how to do that.

How to make Alembic work with SQLModel models?

Comment: What do you mean by "get alembic to recognise the below model"? I tried to run migrations with alembic a couple of days ago and changes were recognisable

Comment: Anyway I can try to spell out detail how I got it all working.

Comment: If you got the changes to be recognisable that's all I was after, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There should be info about that in [Advanced user guide](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/advanced/) soon with better explanation than mine but here is how I made Alimbic migrations work.

First of all run `alembic init migrations` in your console to generate migrations folder. Inside **migrations** folder should be empty **versions** subfolder,**env.py** file, **script.py.mako** file.
In **script.py.mako** file we should add line `import sqlmodel` somewhere around these two lines

```
#script.py.mako
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlmodel # added
```

Then we should edit **env.py** file

```
#env.py
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

from app.models import * # necessarily to import something from file where your models are stored

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = None 
# comment line above and instead of that write
target_metadata = SQLModel.metadata
```

While writing came up with an idea that you forgot to import something from your **models.py** (or anywhere else your models are stored). And that was the main problem

Also, an important note would be saving changes in your models by pressing **ctrl(CMD) + S** - there are some issues with that.

Finally,running

```
 alembic revision --autogenerate -m "your message"
```

should generate a new .py file in **versions** folder with your changes.
And

```
 alembic upgrade head
```

Applies your changes to DB.

Comment: As mentioned at [TestDriven.io Post](https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-sqlmodel/) too.

Comment: Three is a PR for this here, you can look in the comments and see the instructions there too:
https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/pull/512

Comment: It would be better to use `from app import models` instead of `from app.models import *` in `env.py`

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a fastapi-alembic and SQLmodel integration with async PostgreSQL database
https://github.com/jonra1993/fastapi-sqlmodel-alembic