# How we can migrate database in sqlmodel?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

```py
class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(primary_key=True)
    name: str
    age: int = Field(default=None)
    status:str
```

I created the table using `SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)`, when I changed the type of status to `str` and run the `create_all()` method again the type of status did not change in the database. Is there any way to migrate the database like Django or flask-migrate?

Comment: [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: It's SQLAlchemy behind the scenes, so alembic would be the natural choice for migrations (which is the same as used by `flask-migrate`, iirc).

Comment: This is a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932099/how-to-get-alembic-to-recognise-sqlmodel-database-model

Comment: In question @Greg mentioned I tried to answer it. Hope it helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Alembic to recognise SQLModel database model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932099/how-to-get-alembic-to-recognise-sqlmodel-database-model)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to drop the table manually and reload the app.

But if you want a more automated and reliable solution check the following link:

https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/85

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).