migrate table constraint added to SQLModel
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, JSON, Relationship, CheckConstraint
class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    balance: Decimal = Field(sa_column_args=[CheckConstraint('balance>=0')])

I want to set the balance limit to >= 0. But after adding, Alembic does not create a migration and does not apply it to the PostgreSQL table.
How can I create a constraint for the "balance" column?

possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68932099/2144390
